# How can I keep the vertical Y axis the same? Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, you can overlay one stat over another in the graphs that are drawn. For example, you can overlay "Avg. Page Load Time (sec)" over "Avg. Server Connection Time (sec)" (under Behaviour, Site Speed, Overview).

[image: Example graph]

However, I've noticed that the vertical scale for each line is not the same, even though the units are the same. The top of the graph is 40 seconds for Avg. Page Load Time, and it's 2 seconds for Avg. Server Connection Time.

How can I make the vertical scale for the Y axis the same for both stats?

Answer (score 2):

In Google Analytics you just can't. Export data and visualize it in Excel - only there you have full freedom on setting up your axis.